# $route.name and/or $router.currentRoute.name return null when I'm calling in CREATED hook

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

Here is my router

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Home from '../views/Home.vue'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

  const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: '/boys',
    name: 'Boys',
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "boys" */ '../views/Boys.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/girls',
    name: 'Girls',
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "girls" */ '../views/Girls.vue')
  }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  linkExactActiveClass: "active__nav",
  routes
})

export default router
```

Here is my whole component, I'm putting whole code just in case

```
<template>
    <div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <router-link v-for="(menuItem, i) in menu"
                         :key="menuItem.name"
                         :to="{name : menuItem.route}"
                         tag="li">
                    <p class="menu__item__name"
                       @mouseover="ft_hover($event, i, 20)"
                       @mouseleave="ft_hover($event, i, 0)"
                       @click="ft_click($event, i)">
                        {{ menuItem.title }}
                    </p>
                <div class="animate__link" :style="menuItem.styleNavBar"></div>
            </router-link>
        </ul>
    </div>

</template>

<script>
    import MenuBar from "@/store/menu.js"; // importing menu with data

    export default {
        namespaced: true,
        name: "TheNav",
        data(){
            return {
                menu: MenuBar.navBar
            }
        },
        methods: {
            ft_click(e, i) // it just do animation on clicked Nav
            {
                this.menu.forEach( (el) => {
                    el.styleNavBar.width = 0 + '%';
                    el.active = false;
                })
                this.menu[i].active = true;
                this.menu[i].styleNavBar.width = 80 + '%';
                console.log(this.$route.name); // here I tried console log $route on click on menu
            },
            ft_hover(e, i, width) // it just do animation on hovered Nav
            {
                if(this.menu[i].active !== true)
                this.menu[i].styleNavBar.width = width + '%';
            }
        },
        created()
        {
            console.log(this.$router.currentRoute.name); // here is where I have issue
        }
    }
```

I want to get router name when I'm loading a page for a first time. And `$router.currentRoute.name` or `$route.name` works perfectly fine if I load main page first as localhost:8080 it returns 'Home'. But if I load localhost:8080/girls or localhost:8080/boys it returns 'null'. I tried debug it. I have a method ft_click which do some animation on clicked menu, and for my surprise it prints out router name right on every click what I do on navigation, except it prints it ONE STEP BEHIND, so if I was on Home page and clicked on `Boys` it prints `Home`, then if I click Girls it prints `Boys`. I don't know if that related to my issue tho, but it gives at least an idea that with my routes everything is good is just I guess I dont know something, thats why it doesnt work....

also in case if @store/menu is needed

```
export default {
        navBar: [{
            title: 'Main',
            route: 'Home',
            styleNavBar: {
                background: "#d1d8e0",
                width: 0 + '%'
            },
            active: false
        },
        {
            title: 'Girls',
            route: 'Girls',
            styleNavBar: {
                background: "#f8c291",
                width: 0 + '%'
            },
            active: false
        },
        {
            title: 'Boys',
            route: 'Boys',
            styleNavBar: {
                background: "#34495e",
                width: 0 + '%'
            },
            active: false
        }
]}
```